# How to get all products collection for special category

Tags: magento-1, collection, filter, product-collection

I am looking for function which is similar to `getLoadedProductCollection` and which retrieves all products from this category with selected filters, not only those I can see on current page like `getLoadedProductCollection` do.

I've tried to do:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('collection_price')
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('special_price')
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('name');
```

But it retrieves all products from whole store, not only products from current category with selected filters. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter product collection by any category using below code.

```
$cat_id = 'Your category id here';

    $ProductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $cat_id))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

You can also use below code to get product of specific category.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                    ->load(cat_id)
                    ->getProductCollection();
```

Comment: Nice, it works. Any ideas how to apply current filters to this function?

Comment: You can use registry to get current category Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();

Comment: @Mr.AP hope its work for you? for product page there will be multiple category so you need to get array of categories assign to product